# Remove evey substring after a given character in a list

Tags: r, list

I have a list that has the following structure:

`[1] "Atp|Barcelona|Concentration(ng/mL)|8|FALSE"`

I want to extract the third element (separating by the `|` symbol, and removing for the given string everything that is after the `(` symbol.

So I would get this character:

`[1] "Concentration"`

What I do is first split by the `|` symbol. Then, get the third element of the generated list.
In order to be able to use gsub I convert to character, and then I apply gsub function, like follows.

```
y <- "Atp|Barcelona|Concentration(ng/mL)|8|FALSE"
y <- strsplit(y,  "\\|")
y <- y[[1]][3]
y <- as.character(y)
gsub("(.*","",y)
```

However, this error is prompted:

```
invalid regular expression '(.*', reason 'Missing ')''
```

Comment: You have to escape the `(`, try `gsub("\\(.*", "", y)`

Comment: @Roybatty, it is considered polite to accept an answer that has resolved your query.  If you accept answers, people may be willing to help in your future queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `strsplit` with `unlist` here:

```
x <- "Atp|Barcelona|Concentration(ng/mL)|8|FALSE"
output <- unlist(strsplit(x, "\\|"))[3]
output

[1] "Concentration(ng/mL)"
```

If some inputs might have have at least two `|` separators, then you may first check the size of the vector output from the above before trying to access the third element.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need `y <- as.character(y)`, since the result would already be of class "character".

Second, your problem lies in the pattern inside `gsub()`, where you need to escape the opening bracket. Therefore your full code should be:

```
y <- "Atp|Barcelona|Concentration(ng/mL)|8|FALSE"
y <- strsplit(y,  "\\|")
y <- y[[1]][3]
gsub("\\(.*","",y)

[1] "Concentration"
```